# why does .add() method in jquery sort the set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

i was adding many dom objects (svgg elements) around 3000 to an empty jquery set using .add() jquery method but it takes a lot of time and the ui freezes when the javascript is running.And i found out that add every time sorts the set which is taking a lot of time but why is there a need of sorting.
here is the javascript code.

```
var list= $jquery();
for(x=0;x<no_of_objects(around 3k+ in my case);x++){
list.add(items[x]);
}
```

Comment: Read documentation: https://api.jquery.com/add/ (... resulting collection from .add() will be sorted in document order ...)

Comment: What is `items` exactly?

Comment: If `items` is an array of DOM node references, you can pass it directly into the jQuery constructor: `var list = $(items);`

Comment: What do you need a jQuery collection of 3000 elements for?

Comment: items is a collection of ids of svg g elements.....i was working on a code and i have seen that using add() after modifying ids like this, list.add('#'+items[x].replace(/\./g, "\\.")) produces svg g element but passing it into constructor simply return the modified ids.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what jQuery docs say about .add() method:

> When all elements are members of the same document, the resulting collection from .add() will be sorted in document order; that is, in order of each element's appearance in the document. If the collection consists of elements from different documents or ones not in any document, the sort order is undefined. To create a jQuery object with elements in a well-defined order and without sorting overhead, use the $(array_of_DOM_elements) signature.

https://api.jquery.com/add/

So if you want to preserve the order, try $(items) as they suggest..?

Answer (score 2):

Because jQuerys `add()` does not only append a value to a set, it actually creates a new sorted collection and then adds the value to it..

For more info, take a look at the docs: https://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this elements in loop to element not attached to DOM, and then attach them in one move. Each time you modify DOM, browser must recalculate view.

```
var list = new Array();

for(x=0;x<no_of_objects(around 3k+ in my case);x++){
  list.add(items[x]);
}

$('#list').append(list.join(""));
```

Comment: You're right about what happens when the DOM is modified, but the code in the OP is *not* modifying the DOM.